# Loop through whether a number exists, if not iterate by one until number does not exist

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, for-loop

I have the following code which loops through all of the `moduleId` in a course, for example the output of for one course is

`0000`
`0001`
`0002`
`0003`

```
var self = this;
$('#addCourseBtn').on('click', function () {
    var templateId = self.courseTemplate.get('ID');
    var num = 0;
    var courseString = ("000" + num).substr(-4, 4);
    console.log(courseString);


    var i, s, courseModuleList = (self.courseTemplate.get('ModuleIndexList')), len = courseModuleList.length;

    for (i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        if (i in courseModuleList) {
            s = courseModuleList[i];
            if (self.modules.get(s) != undefined) {
                var moduleId = (self.modules.get(s).get('Id'));
            }
        }
    }
});
```

I want to be able to check whether a number exists beginning with `0000`, if that exists iterate by one to `0001` then if that exists iterate to `0002` etc. then if it doesn't exist `courseString = "0004"` Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: That's completely unclear. Read [ask]!

Comment: Are you wanting to return 'the lowest id that isn't already used'? And is there a limit on how high that id can be?

Comment: @SMcCrohan Yes, I am wanting to return the lowest id that isn't already used, the limit is `9999`